# Xamarin http webservice issue

Tags: xamarin

I m trying to use http request webservice issue is that when we post wrong username and password the login service generate exception and it can't return any value in async calls.

Comment: Show us what you have done

Comment: Johan please check this url code snippet attached here http://hastebin.com/narucudufi.avrasm

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet would help assist with the problem ...

However using a try catch should help you catch your exception and prevent application from crashing and handling the exceptions accordingly.

As seen in my sample code below I cater for the incorrect details entered / connectivity problems. I peform the http async request then parse the xml to my model handling the exceptions accordingly

```
                var response = await WebRequestHelper.MakeAsyncRequest(url, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Login Successfull" + "result.IsSuccessStatusCode" + response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    result = result.Replace("<xml>", "<LoginResult>").Replace("</xml>", "</LoginResult>");
                    loginResult = XMLHelper.FromXml<LoginResult>(result);

                    if (loginResult != null)
                    {
                        login.Type = ResultType.OK;
                        login.Result = loginResult;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        login.Type = ResultType.WrongDetails;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Login Failed" + "result.IsSuccessStatusCode" + response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
                    login.Type = ResultType.WrongDetails;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                login.Type = ResultType.ConnectivityProblem;
            }
```

#### Web Request

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> content)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json");

        if (content == null)
        {
            content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, encodedContent);

        return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping the response in a generic ServiceResponse where you can store the exceptions. `await` methods can be included in try/catch blocks so the standard process can be followed.

E.G.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> PostAsync<T>(String address, object dto){
    var content = Serializer.SerializeObject (dto);
    var response = await client.PostAsync (
        address, 
        new StringContent (content));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        try {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
            return new ServiceResponse<T> (Serializer.DeserializeObject<T> (responseString),
                response.StatusCode);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new ServiceResponse<T> (response.StatusCode, ex);
        }
    } else {
        return new ServiceResponse<T> (response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

With the `ServiceResponse` defined as :

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set;}

    public T Value { get; set;}

    public String Content { get; set;}

    public Exception Error {get;set;}

    public ServiceResponse(T value, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode){
        this.Value = value;
        this.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }

    public ServiceResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, Exception error = null){
        this.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        this.Error = error;
    }
}
```

This will give you a clean way of managing all your HTTP responses and any errors that may occur.